# Safe Remove doesn't work anymore in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

Before today I could remove external hard-wares with `Safe Remove` in Win 7 x64.
But nowadays, when I click on below button nothing happen! And I can't remove external hardware with Safe Remove anymore.

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell what's wrong with it because the way you do it... I'd do it the same way. I've been looking on the web and I found this for you. It's not the same way as you do it so maybe it can be helpful for you:

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/10169-safely-remove-hardware-eject-device.html

> Click on the Safely Remove Hardware notification area icon, and click on the Eject drive option for the listed drive that you want to eject.
>
> When you see this notification message below ["Safe to Remove Hardware"], you can now safely remove the device from the computer.

Answer (score 3):

I was having issues with the safely remove hardware button popping up when I would click on it. I searched the web and luckily found the solution.

Check your services and make sure the bluetooth service is started and set to "automatic startup".

Comment: oh man, thank you so much. It's everything but intuitive, it's the last service I would have think of!

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned it was okay up until today, I strongly suggest doing a [**system restore**](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/system-restore-windows-7.htm) back a few days and see if this resolves the problem.